# Hyphenation does not work with acro and luatex, but with pdftex

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking, luatex, hyphenation, acronyms

I'm using luatex 0.70.1 together with acro 1.2 and I have the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{DNA}{
    short=DNA,
    long=Desoxyribonukleinsäure
}

\begin{document}
Das ist ein sehr langer Satz und er wird an seinem Ende leider nicht richtig umgebrochen: DNA-Sequenzierung

Das ist ein sehr langer Satz und er wird an seinem Ende leider nicht richtig umgebrochen: \acs{DNA}-Sequenzierung
\end{document}
```

Document looks normal with pdftex (both lines wrapped after dash), but when using luatex the 2nd line continues into the margin. I would have posted images, but due to the fact that this is my first post the systems doesn't allow it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The following is not a full solution, for sure, but more of a short-term fix: you can (re)enable hyphenation after `DNA-` by writing `\acs{DNA}-\hspace{0pt}Sequenzierung`. If this sequence (pun intended) occurs frequently in your document, you may want to consider creating a little macro, such as `\newcommand{\DNAS}{\acs{DNA}-\hspace{0pt}Sequenzierung}`.

Comment: Perhaps the lualatex format does not contains the same hyphenation patterns than the pdflatex format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with the different hyphenation algorithm used by LuaTeX. I don't really know the details, but here's what's shown when I put `DNA-Sequenzierung` and `\acs{DNA}-Sequenzierung` in a box and make LuaTeX show it.

#### `\sbox0{DNA-Sequenzierung}`

```
\hbox(6.8872+1.94397)x88.4784, direction TLT
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 D
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 N
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 A
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 -
.\discretionary
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 S
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 q
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 u
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 z
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 u
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 g
```

#### `\sbox0{\acs{DNA}-Sequenzierung}`

```
\hbox(6.8872+1.94397)x88.4784, direction TLT
.\hbox(6.8872+0.0)x22.63336, direction TLT
..\hbox(6.8872+0.0)x22.63336, direction TLT
..\hbox(6.8872+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 22.63336fil, direction TLT
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
...\T1/cmr/m/n/10 D
...\T1/cmr/m/n/10 N
...\T1/cmr/m/n/10 A
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 -
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 S
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 q
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 u
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 z
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 r
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 u
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.\T1/cmr/m/n/10 g
```

In the first case LuaTeX puts a `\discretionary` item after the hyphen, while it doesn't in the second case, probably because it thinks that the hyphen is at the start of a word (it comes after a box which is not part of the word).

This does not happen with pdfLaTeX, because the `\discretionary` item is inserted at a later stage.

It's probably better, in any case, using the `babel` shortcuts:

```
Das ist ein sehr langer Satz und er wird an seinem Ende leider 
nicht richtig umgebrochen: DNA"=Sequenzierung

Das ist ein sehr langer Satz und er wird an seinem Ende leider 
nicht richtig umgebrochen: \acs{DNA}"=Sequenzierung
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: OK, tested that myself using the \showhyphens{} command and it looks indeed as if the hyphenated word is "-Sequenzierung". I thought the acronym replacement would happen first and hyphenation later after eventually having the word replaced. Unfortunately shorthands don't work within an acronym definition.